# C# Play generated sound (present in array) on default speaker & receive using default microphone

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, naudio

I am developing universal windows app (C#/Xaml) I am able to play a sound from .wav file but now I want to play sound which I am generating on runtime. It will be generated well before playing. How Can I play generated sound (present in array) on default speakers. And I also want to receive the played sound (i know there will be noise NO ISSUES) using default microphone and put the recorded data in array. Any help would be appreciable.
Regards

Comment: I'm confused about what you are doing, this question is a little broad. "How Can I play generated sound (present in array) on default speakers.", you mean your sound input is stored in an array? Then why you want to play it and catch it to store again in an array? Could you please post some code, what have you done for now?

Comment: Actually I am developing transmitter and receiver for sound radar. I have data (transmitter's output present in array/vector) to transmit using sound card/speaker. and then I want to receive the transmitted data on which I will do processing. Currently I am using "Audio graph"